# Max Distance between 2 points in a data set and identifying the points

Tags: python, algorithm, matlab, numpy

I have a matrix consisting of x,y,z coordinates of several points. I would like to find the extremum points i.e. the two points that are farthest apart.

I could figure out a way in matlab, but i need it in Python

Here is the code in matlab

```
A = randint(500,3,[-5 5]);
D=pdist(A);
D=squareform(D);
[N,I]=max(D(:));
[I_row, I_col] = ind2sub(size(D),I);
```

pdist gives the distance between pairs of points(i,j).
squareform gives the matrix output
In last two steps I attempt to find the indices of the matrix I_row, I_col..

Points I_row and I_col have the max distance..

Could anybody suggest me an efficient way in python as all my other codes are in Python.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have `scipy`, you have exact equivalent for most of matlab core functions :

```
from numpy import random, nanmax, argmax, unravel_index
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist, squareform

A = random.randint(-5,5, (500,3))
D = pdist(A)
D = squareform(D);
N, [I_row, I_col] = nanmax(D), unravel_index( argmax(D), D.shape )
```

You can also get it in pure python using `itertools` :

```
from itertools import combinations
from random import randint

A = [[randint(-5,5) for coord in range(3)] for point in range(500)]

def square_distance(x,y): return sum([(xi-yi)**2 for xi, yi in zip(x,y)])    

max_square_distance = 0
for pair in combinations(A,2):
    if square_distance(*pair) > max_square_distance:
        max_square_distance = square_distance(*pair)
        max_pair = pair
```

Comment: This answer is in _O(N^2)_ time and memory, which will fail for large datasets.

Answer (score 18):

All the other answers here take *O(N^2)* time and space. That's terrible.

Instead, recognize that the two farthest points in a dataset lie on the set's convex hull. Since hulls can be computed in *O(N log N)* time in 3D this forms an efficient prefilter. In my testing on a dataset with 16,000,000 points the convex hull contained only 420 points.

The farthest points on the hull can be found in *O(H log H)* time, though this is harder to implement in Python. So we can instead at that point fall back to the *O(N^2)* cdist solutions.

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial import ConvexHull
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist

N = 16000000

# Find a convex hull in O(N log N)
points = np.random.rand(N, 3)   # N random points in 3-D

# Returned 420 points in testing
hull = ConvexHull(points)

# Extract the points forming the hull
hullpoints = points[hull.vertices,:]

# Naive way of finding the best pair in O(H^2) time if H is number of points on
# hull
hdist = cdist(hullpoints, hullpoints, metric='euclidean')

# Get the farthest apart points
bestpair = np.unravel_index(hdist.argmax(), hdist.shape)

#Print them
print([hullpoints[bestpair[0]],hullpoints[bestpair[1]]])
```

Comment: Unfortunately `ConvexHull` crashes if the points are in line or every point is the same, because it tries to build a simplex. Any idea how to handle that?

Comment: @MeredithHeskethFortescue I would look at the scipy Convexhull specification, maybe there is some word about it. If you read about [qhull options](http://www.qhull.org/html/qh-optq.htm) you can pass, maybe you will find what you seek. 

If none available, I think I would deal with points being the same by removing duplicates before running the convex hull calculation. 

For the case with all points in a line, perhaps you could just use information about that fact and compute the distance between furthermost points on the line via other method.

Comment: Using the ```pdist``` function instead of ```cdist``` reduces the complexity of the algorithm because it doesn't calculate the distance between points twice and the distance from a point to itself, and it's therefore faster. However, the process of getting indexes in python of the farthest points removes the benefit from ```pdist```.  ```hullpoints[np.array(np.triu_indices(len(hullpoints),1))[:,pdist(hullpoints).argmax()]]```

Answer (score 2):

This will give you pairs of indexes of the points in A that are furthest apart as temp_b.  Note that it will include both directions such as (8, 222) and (222, 8) in the list.  I will leave it to you remove them if you want.

```
import numpy as np
import random as rd
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist
from scipy.spatial.distance import squareform

A = np.array([np.array([rd.randint(-5,5) for x in range(3)]) for y in range(500)])
D=pdist(A)
D=squareform(D)
temp = np.where(D == D.max())
temp_b = zip(temp[0],temp[1])
```

Comment: This is _O(N^2)_ in time and space.

Answer (score 0):

You can use scipy's [`pdist`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.pdist.html)

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist, squareform
A = np.random.randint(-5, 5, [500, 3])
D = squareform(pdist(A))
N = np.max(D)
I = np.argmax(D)
I_row, I_col = np.unravel_index(I, D.shape)
```

Comment: This is _O(N^2)_ in time and space.